# I want to avoid 'floating point error' in C program

Tags: c

I would like to avoid 'floating point error in this code.

A purpose of this code is to gain 'The average of whole numbers' but the number of 'whole numbers' is limited by the input of users. Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num=0;
    int limit;
    int result=0;

    printf("number of integer: ");
    scanf("&d", &limit);

    while(num<limit)
    {
        int output;
        printf("Input integer : ");
        scanf("%d", &output);
        result += output;
        num++;
    }
    printf("average of total integer: %d \n", result/limit);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: No homework, but i study alone with a book.

Comment: It's already fine. You don't do any floating point calculations so there can be no floating point errors.

Comment: What "floating point error" are you getting? Or were you just speculating that you could get one?

Comment: The `scanf` that reads `limit` should have a format of `"%d"` instead of `"&d"`

Comment: What are you expecting to get from `scanf("&d", &limit);`? Oh, and dividing an int by an int, yields an int. Not a float. Declare `result` and `limit` as a `float` or `double`

Comment: @Pat oh I am about to percieve this problem!!! Thank you!

Comment: @Elias Vab Ootegem  "&d" That is my mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide 2 integers, the result is also an integer.

To return a float, you need to cast one of the arguments as a float.

So your last line becomes

```
printf("average of total integer: %f \n", result/(float)limit);
```

Comment: Curious as to why you cast to `float` rather than `double`?  Note: the quotient `result/(float)limit` is converted to `double` before being passed to `printf()`.

Comment: @chux Are you sure about that? The type of the result is the type of the longer argument. So in this case it will be float.

Comment: @Bartlomiej Lewandowski Agree that your "it", the quotient, is `float`.  But "it" is passed to `printf(char *format, ...)` and being a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) argument, it goes through default argument promotions which in this case is: `float` are promoted to `double`.  C11 §6.5.2.2 6  That's why if you pass a `float` or `double` to `printf()` it uses the same format specifier as `float` are promoted to `double`.

Comment: @chux Thank you, I was not aware of this promotion when passing to printf.

Answer (score 1):

As the result of two `integer` dividing is also an integer,so it as

```
printf("average of total integer: %f \n", result/(float)limit);
```

when you type cast the variable `limit` to float what happens is that `result` will be implicitly converted to `float` and so the result is a `float`.

Comment: The other answer was 9 minutes before yours, and yours didn't add any substantial news.

Comment: @glglgl my internet is down.